# Instantiate global services in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am currently developing a new system at work, using AngularJS. And the application currently has many Controllers, Services and Directives, and many dependencies.

The system has about 9 services, and most of them are reused in multiple controllers, so I injected them into the parent controller so they can be accessible by children controllers. Each service stores data used throughout the whole system.

However, as the development progresses, I find that it is getting harder and harder to manage, and in some cases, I have to do a bit of hack to be able to use the instance of a service at different places.

My question here is, instead of injecting all services into the main controller, should I instead instantiate them in the app.js file as global variables... but I don't really like the idea of having global variables, so besides doing this, would there be any alternative solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Services are singletons in Angular, so you should just inject them where ever you need them. It's not necessary to inject them in to an ancestor and propegate it down. Just inject it directly into the child as well. There is only one instance of the service regardless, so why not just make it easier that way?

Comment: Yeah, I previously did that, however, for some reason, data stored in services could not be retrieved from a child when injecting the service into it.