# AngularJS: global access to services?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I've got a simple setup, but I'm probably not "thinking like a JS programmer."  There are multiple controllers, for different pages, that all call a routine for ajaxing to PHP.  Simplified version below.  It's working, but I'm obviously not setting it up correctly, since I've got to pass all these service objects through to every single call...How should this be set up?

```
app.controller('ctrlA', $scope, $http, $location, $sce) {
    app.db_read($scope, $http, {param: 1}, $sce, 
         function() {// succeeded},
         function() {// failed}
    )
}

app.controller('ctrlB', $scope, $http, $location, $sce) {
    app.db_read($scope, $http, {param: 1}, $sce, 
         function() {// succeeded},
         function() {// failed}
    )
}
...
app.db_read = function($scope, $http, payload, $location, $sce) {
    $http.post('url', {request: 'read', data: payload})
         .then(function(data) {$scope.data = data},
         function(error) {$scope.displayError = $sce.trustAsHtml(error)}
    )
}
```

I looked at this question: [Instantiate global services in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26498649/instantiate-global-services-in-angularjs)
...where the answer appears as, "Services are singletons in Angular, so you should just inject them where ever you need them."
Unfortunately, I don't know how to "inject" a service into my db_read function.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: What you have is way off track. Angular has module components that are services and those are what you would inject into another component like a controller or directive. There are lots of tutorials and blog posts all over the web and on angular docs site about how to use services. Suggest you study some to get a more fundamental understanding off what they are and how they are used. `app.db_read ` is totally off base also

Comment: If you don't have an answer, why comment?

Comment: Because this isn't a code writing or tutorial service. Don't take it personal...trying to give you some constructive suggestions. One of the major parts of web development is doing research and learning ...always

Comment: I studied a lot.  Couldn't find materials that explained this in a way I could understand.  That's what brought me here.

Comment: Try the tutorial on angular docs site https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

Comment: Last time I looked at the Angular docs, they were awful.  But now they're not so bad...actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The services mentionned in the post you linked to are not the service objects that you are currently passing to your functions (which are services provided by Angular), but custom services.

A common pattern used in Angular projects it to put your db_read function in a factory function that returns a service object.

```
app.factory('dbservice', function($http) {

    return {
        db_read: function(payload) {
            return $http.post('url', {request: 'read', data:payload})
        }   
    }

})
```

It is that factory function you want to inject in your controllers.

```
app.controller('ctrlA', function($scope, $sce, dbservice) {

    $scope.read = function(payload) {
        return dbservice.db_read(payload)
            .then(function(data) {$scope.data = data},
             function(error) {$scope.displayError = $sce.trustAsHtml(error))
    }
})
```

You can then pass the payload from your controller's template:

```
<button ng-click="read({param: 1})"></button>
```

Or from within your controller:

```
    var payload = {param: 1}
    return dbservice.db_read(payload)
        .then(function(data) {$scope.data = data},
             function(error) {$scope.displayError = $sce.trustAsHtml(error))
```